# Переключение GPU на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, видео, youtube, gpu

Имеется macbook pro с двумя видеоадаптерами - intel и nvidia.

При просмотре видео на youtube в качестве 1440 и выше, система автоматически переключается на nvidia. Но если я играю видео в таком же качестве (и выше) через HTML5 Video, оно тормозит, но переключение на более мощный видеоадаптер не происходит.

Пример видео на ютубе http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U

Как заставить систему переключать gpu?

Comment: Хм, кому помешал мой комментарий с указанием ТС какую технологию нвидиа искать?

Comment: @Visman не знаю, напишите ещё раз.